# Is a Google Sheets fit model a valid place to retrieve starting parameters for nls()?

Tags: r, google-sheets, non-linear-regression, nls

I am trying to fit an exponential model of form `y = a*e^(x*b)` in R to the data I have ran below, using the `nls()` function. I have read here and in other places that I need to feed the model reasonable parameters for `a` and `b`, but the way about getting those starting parameters seems very variable, and many of the suggested ways were methods that I could not find elaborations on. One suggestion said that you could copy your data into an Excel spreasheet, fit your model on the graph, and adjust the parameters until it appeared to fit the data reasonably well. Well, I went into Google Sheets, I inserted a chart based on the data below, and then selected `Customize > Series > Trendline (exponential)`, and it fed me a formula of **5.51e^0.015x** . Are these valid values I could use as my starting parameters? Does Google Sheets produce those effectively, or do I need to do the tinkering method, or try something else? I have read over and over again the importance of choosing proper starting values, so any help on this would be much appreciated. My educational background did not cover non linear models.

```
x       y
19.005  5.49
18.19   6
19.59   5.885
19.93   8.96
17.615  13.85
18.795  2.72
19.11   8.09
19.885  8.11
15.76   6.66
16.48   6.27
15.805  5.375
15.825  3.06
15.985  7.795
15.755  6.255
15.485  5.925
15.475  9.925
16.45   6.055
16.285  5.24
15.92   11.15
16.775  5.57
16.075  3.275
16.475  5.635
16.825  4.72
16.28   2.035
17.26   6.07
17.245  4.9
17.98   8.06
17.35   6.94
18.22   7.8
16.27   12.2
17.555  7.335
16.98   5.76
17.415  7.51
17.5    6.18
```

Comment: Your question is about the appropriate parameterization of a statistical model, it's not really about coding.  You'll find better help on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A methodology comment: Usually, when your computational solution is highly dependent on starting values, it means you have some kind of "flatness" in some direction, hence, model identifiability problems (for that specific dataset).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the data shown in the question we could just use a starting value of b = 1. If we use the `plinear` algorithm of `nls` then no starting value is needed for the linear parameter, `a`.  In that case `a` should not be specified in the formula as it is implied already.  It will be reported as `.lin` in the output.  In the first line of code we sort `DF` giving `DFs` to facilitate later plotting.

```
DFs <- DF[order(DF$x), ]
fo <- y ~ exp(b * x)
fm <- nls(fo, DFs, start = list(b = 1), algorithm = "plinear")
```

However, if `nls` does not work with some other data then since `y` is strictly positive we can take logs of both sides to get a linear model `fm0` which can be fit with `lm` to get a starting value for `b`.  Use the `plinear` algorithm as above to avoid having to specify a starting value for `a`.  `DFs` and `fo` are from above.

```
fm0 <- lm(log(y) ~ x, DFs)
fm2 <- nls(fo, DFs, start = list(b = coef(fm0)[[2]]), algorithm = "plinear")
fm2

## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: y ~ exp(b * x)
##    data: DFs
##       b    .lin 
## 0.02819 4.10908 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 205.6
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 3 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.073e-06

plot(y ~ x, DFs)
lines(fitted(fm2) ~ x, DFs, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "x       y
19.005  5.49
18.19   6
19.59   5.885
19.93   8.96
17.615  13.85
18.795  2.72
19.11   8.09
19.885  8.11
15.76   6.66
16.48   6.27
15.805  5.375
15.825  3.06
15.985  7.795
15.755  6.255
15.485  5.925
15.475  9.925
16.45   6.055
16.285  5.24
15.92   11.15
16.775  5.57
16.075  3.275
16.475  5.635
16.825  4.72
16.28   2.035
17.26   6.07
17.245  4.9
17.98   8.06
17.35   6.94
18.22   7.8
16.27   12.2
17.555  7.335
16.98   5.76
17.415  7.51
17.5    6.18"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate the thorough help. I've marked this question as answered now. Do you have any readings you would recommend that could maybe strengthen my understanding of non-linear models and their design?

Comment: *Nonlinear Regression with R*, Ritz & Streibig.
*Nonlinear Parameter Optimization Using R Tools*, Nash.
*Nonlinear Regression Analysis and Its Applications*, Bates & Watts.

Answer (score 0):

I composed a similar answer to @G.Grothendieck's ... the general point is that you *could* use Google sheets, or Excel, or some other tool, to get starting values for `nls()`, but there's no need to.

I loaded your data using `dd <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="x y\n19.005  5.49 ...")`

### fit log-linear model

```
m1 <- lm(log(y)~x,data=dd)
cc <- coef(m1)
## (Intercept)           x 
##   1.1404581   0.0399405
```

The log-linear model doesn't actually give quite the same answer as `nls()` (although plenty good enough for starting values), because it makes different implicit assumptions about the error distribution (log-linear assumes that variance is constant *on the log scale*, while non-linear fits assume that variance is constant on the original scale, unless you specify otherwise).

### log-link GLM

Another useful alternative is a *generalized* linear model fit with a Gaussian response and a log link.  This actually fits exactly the same model as `nls()`

```
m2 <- glm(y~x, family=gaussian(link="log"), data=dd)
cc2 <- coef(m2)
## (Intercept)           x 
##  1.41320439  0.02819136
```

... which you can see if you compare these coefficient values to the ones that `nls()` finds ...

```
s <- list(a=exp(cc2[[1]]), b= cc2[[2]])
m3 <- nls(y~a*exp(b*x), data=dd, start=s)
coef(m3)
```

[image]

Some different ways to make predictions and visualize them ...

```
par(las=1,bty="l")
plot(y~x,data=dd)
lines(dd$x,exp(predict(m1)))
lines(dd$x,exp(cc[1])*exp(cc[2]*dd$x), col=2,lty=2)

lines(dd$x, predict(m2,type="response"), col=3)
lines(dd$x, exp(cc2[1])*exp(cc2[2]*dd$x), col=4,lty=2)
legend("topright",col=1:4,lty=rep(1:2,2),
       c("lm(log) predict","lm(log) formula","glm predict","glm formula"))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It means so much to have the help of the community like this. Are there any recommendations of readings you might have, to get a better grasp on these non-linear model designs?